# Как изменить календарь Datepicker v4 Docs

Tags: javascript

Я использую [Datepicker v4 Docs](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#linked-pickers).

Возможно ли мой код сделать без участие bootstrap-datetimepicker, а просто type=data, ну или type=text, главное что без подключение к bootstrap-datetimepicker

```js
  $(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  minDate: moment().add(0, 'days'),
  maxDate: moment().add(3, 'days')
  }).on('dp.change', function (selected) {
  $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker('minDate',selected.date.add(60, 'days'));
  $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
      });
  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
  format: 'DD.MM.YYYY',
  minDate: moment().add(0, 'days')
  }).on('dp.change', function (selected) {
  $(this).datetimepicker('hide');
  });;
   });
```

```html
   <div class="row">
   <div class='col form-group'>
Начало
   <div class="form-group">
   <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
   <input type='text' class="form-control" />
   <span class="input-group-addon">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
   </span>
 </div>
  </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<div class="row">
<div class='col form-group'>
&nbsp;
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2' >
<input type='text' class="form-control"  disabled="true"/>
<span class="input-group-addon">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
  </span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: datepicker v4 - отличная вещь, но вы ее не используете. у вас открывается стандартный календарик. весь ваш js-код нерабочий, он требует подключить необходимые библиотеки в html

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lp9mocqr/5/)

Comment: Какие библиотеки надо подключить?

Comment: указанная в комментарии ссылка - рабочая, там все хорошо подключено. я не очень понимаю в чем проблема: вместо одной библиотеки подключить другую? календарей много. я согласен, что использовать стандартный календарь (<input type="date">) - не лучшая идея (не поддерживается во многих браузерах). но если надо просто показать и забыть, то стандартный календарь - самое простое.

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ - вот такой например. но вы должны определиться с css-фреймвоком: bootstrap, jquery ui, ... (их десятки). и использовать соответствующий компонент.